# Integral of fraction of product of trigonometric functions

Tags: integration, analysis, trigonometry

I have encountered a problem with integrating 
$$
\int \frac{1}{\sin(4x) \sin(2x)}dx
$$

I thought about substituting for $2x$, but I don't know, what to do after the substitution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using $\sin2A=2\sin A\cos A,$

$$\sin4x\sin2x=2\sin^22x\cos2x$$

$$\frac1{\sin4x\sin2x}=\frac1{2\sin^22x\cos2x}=\frac{\cos2x}{2\sin^22x(1-\sin^22x)}$$

Set $\sin2x=u$

In general for $\int\sin^my\cos^{2n+1}y\ dy=\int\sin^my(1-\sin^2y)^n\cos y\ dy,$

set $\sin y=v$